# Rails has_one Association (user,company)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :comapny
end

class Comapny < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Hi! i created rails association mentioned above. I want user to create only one company (for example: User with id(1) should only make 1 company only).
But even with has_one i am able to make more then 1 company for user1.
can anyone help?

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :show, :update ]
before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update]
before_action :require_admin, only: [:destroy]

    def index
        @user = User.all
    end
def new
    @user = User.new

end
def create 
   
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
         session[:user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:success] = "Welcome #{@user.username}"
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit 

 @user = User.find(params[:id])

end


def update  
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)  
       flash[:success] = "Account was updated" 
        
    else 
       render 'new'
    end

end
  def show      
     

  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "User is destroyed"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

 private 
 
    def user_params 
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :role, :first_name, :last_name)

end
  def set_user 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

end

def require_same_user
    if current_user != @user and !current_user.admin?
          flash[:danger] = "Not authorized"
      redirect_to user_path
    
    
    end
end

def require_admin
    if logged_in? and !current_user.admin?
      flash[:danger] = "Not authorized"
      redirect_to user_path
    
    
    end
end
end
```

```
**comapny_controller.rb**
class ComapniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comapny, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:create]


  # GET /comapnies or /comapnies.json
  def index
    @comapnies = Comapny.all
  end

  # GET /comapnies/1 or /comapnies/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comapnies/new
  def new
    @comapny = Comapny.new
  end

  # GET /comapnies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comapnies or /comapnies.json
  def create
    @comapny = Comapny.new(comapny_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comapny.save
        format.html { redirect_to comapny_url(@comapny), notice: "Comapny was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comapny }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @comapny.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comapnies/1 or /comapnies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comapny.update(comapny_params)
        format.html { redirect_to comapny_url(@comapny), notice: "Comapny was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comapny }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @comapny.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comapnies/1 or /comapnies/1.json
  def destroy
    @comapny.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comapnies_url, notice: "Comapny was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comapny
      @comapny = Comapny.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def comapny_params
      params.require(:comapny).permit(:name, :year_founded, :user_id)
    end

end
```

```
**Coampny_form.html.erb**
<%= form_with(model: comapny, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if comapny.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comapny.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comapny from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comapny.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :comapny_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :year_founded %>
    <%= form.date_select :year_founded, id: :comapny_year_founded %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id, id: :comapny_user_id,  value: current_user.id  %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I made a typo while generating scaffold of coapmny instead of company. ignore that

Comment: How are you able to create more than one company for a user with the class definitions above? Please share the code that creates more companies per user.

Comment: You need to add an unique index on company.user_id column

Comment: @spickermann i have added user_controller.rb and coapmy_controller.rb + coapmy_form.html.erb
kindly check

Comment: is has_one supposed to let me make only one company or do i need to add restriction in company controller.
i added a before action that doesn't allow me to create new company but when i sign in with different user that method gves error. can anyone tell me a method for that with If ELSE statement

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Add a uniqueness constraint to the db table and a uniqueness validation to the company model:

```
class Comapny < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: true
end
```